# timed out while waiting for program to exit in cs50 ide

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a code that reads information from a memory card (card.raw is the one we are provided but the code uses user input) and extracts the jpegs from it using the signatures that jpegs have of (0xff,0xd8,0xff,0x00 - 0xff). I was getting a segmentation fault because i waws using malloc, but i modified my code and am not using any malloc functions anymore. Now the error i am getting is that it times out while waiting for the program to exit, but i do not see where i could possibly have gone wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check terminal usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //open inputted file and check for valid file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Invalid or missing file.");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buff[512];
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *image;
    char name[8];

    //loop till end of file reached and read a block of input
    while(fread(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, file) > 0)
    {
        //check if found jpeg
        if (buff[0] == 0xff && buff[1] == 0xd8 && buff[2] == 0xff && ((buff[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
        {
            //first jpeg
            if(counter == 0)
            {
                sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                image = fopen(name, "w");
                fwrite(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
                counter++;
            }
            //jpegs after the first
            else
            {
                fclose(image);
                sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                image = fopen(name, "W");
                fwrite(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(buff,sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
        }
    }
    fclose(image);
    fclose(file);
}
```

and the error message im getting is

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( recovers middle images correctly
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
```

Comment: `image = fopen(name, "W");` --> `image = fopen(name, "w");`

Comment: This code looks like it will only work if each "jpeg" is exactly 512 bytes.

Comment: I changed the "W" to "w" but am still getting the same errors.

Comment: 1) open files in binary mode `fopen(..., "rb") /*or wb*/` 2) add `return 0;` for C89 compatability (your cs50 environment targets which C version?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems**

1. As @David Ranieri mentioned in the comments, this typo causes
   seg. fault. Fix it.
2. You attempt to write without any check if image file is opened already for this. I added `else if (image != NULL)` in the code.
3. I know this will sound crazy but the order of variable declarations **matter**.

This order gives segmentation fault.

```
FILE *image;
char name[8];
```

But not this one.

```
char name[8];
FILE *image;
```

I will do some research on SO to understand this. **Any explanations are welcome.**

**Note**; After some experimentation, I realized that when pointer is initialized with `NULL`, the order does not cause seg. fault anymore. So better initialize it.

**The final code (tested in CS50 ide);**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check terminal usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //open inputted file and check for valid file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Invalid or missing file.");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buff[512];
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *image = NULL;
    char name[8];


    //loop till end of file reached and read a block of input
    while(fread(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, file) > 0)
    {
        //check if found jpeg
        if (buff[0] == 0xff && buff[1] == 0xd8 && buff[2] == 0xff && ((buff[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
        {
            //first jpeg
            if(counter == 0)
            {
                sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                image = fopen(name, "w");
                fwrite(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
                counter++;
            }
            //jpegs after the first
            else
            {
                fclose(image);
                sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                image = fopen(name, "w");
                fwrite(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else if(image != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buff,sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
        }
    }
    fclose(image);
    fclose(file);
}
```